# How to calculate age using birth year and death date?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have one column with the year of birth (e.g., 1970) and another with the year, month, and day of death (e.g., 2010-3-7). I'd want to determine the age of death.
What I anticipate from the above example is the age of 40. I tried the code line below but it did not work.

```
(df['death date'].apply(pd.to_datetime) - pd.to_timedelta(df['birth year'].astype(int)*365, unit = 'D')) / np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')
```

Comment: About 80% of people born in 1970 would have been 39 on 2010-3-7. Is it OK to do the subtraction 2010-1970 and get 40?

Comment: Since you only have a year of birth you can just subtract the year of birth from the year of death.

Comment: True, the point is that I don't know when month or day they were born.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following code line can provide me with the age of death:

```
pd.DatetimeIndex(df['death date']).year - df['birth year']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"year_of_birth": ["1970"], "day_of_death": ["2010-03-07"]})
df["age_of_death"] = df.apply(lambda r: (datetime.strptime(r["day_of_death"], "%Y-%m-%d") - datetime.strptime(r["year_of_birth"], "%Y")).days // 365, axis=1)
```

Then the column age_of_death will be the answer, we use datetime to parse the datetime, you can read the doc of datetime for more details.